# SP2010 Welcome Page and Site Structure

Tags: content-and-structure

I am learning sharepoint 2010 and enjoying. I've finally customized the masterpage as per my need and now i have two questions.

1. Which file I need to customize for homepage. a) default.aspx  b)homepage.aspx
2. I want to create my site in the following manner. But dont know what will be the sequence like ..Create Site Collection first ..then Subsite?

About Us
...Company Profile
...Financial Rating

Departments
....Department A
....Department B
....Department C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Assuming you have the Publishing feature enabled, you can change your homepage to whatever you want it to be using the "Welcome Page" option in Site Settings. Choose one of the pages and customize it however you want.

2) This depends entirely on your internal policies - you will always have to create site collections before you create sites, but at the absolute simplest you will want to create a site collection for your root, then create two sites in the root site, one called "About Us" and one called "Departments", and then either create pages in those sites for Company Profile / Financial Rating etc, or create sites inside each of the already existing sub-sites for these sites. At any point you would be able to split off into site collections instead of sub-sites, which would also give you the option to split into different databases.

Comment: thank you Mike and how about the Menu Navigation in the same way like When I hover the Departments it should show sub options for Department A and Department B? will it be created automatically this way I mean the vertical way

Comment: This will only happen automatically if you have a single site collection with two subsites, then many subsites under that. Setting navigation to "Show Sites", and then doing the same for the subsites will allow for this functionality. If you split these out into separate site collections, then you either need to manually craft the navigation (in Site Settings for each of the site collections), or write a custom navigation provider that can handle cross-site-collection automatic navigation.

Comment: Any advise for me to follow recommended approach in my scenario?

Comment: My recommendation is that if you are not going to have a lot of content (<1gb) in each of your sites, put them all in a single site collection. If you are going to have a lot of content in your departments, split them off into individual site collections under a single managed path, and build the navigation structure manually.

Comment: Oh thank you so much Mike. Really appreciate your valuable advise.